# Symfony Prod Cache clear returns error: The service "validator.builder" has a dependency on a non existent service "validat or.mapping.cache.apc"

Tags: caching, symfony, production-environment

When trying to clear cache on prod I get:
The service "validator.builder" has a dependency on a non existent service "validat or.mapping.cache.apc".

Symfony app is on ver 3.0.9. It works well in development on Dev Environment.
How do  I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem for anyone who bumps into this.
Somehow the config file created by Symfony when I created the project had in the config_prod.yml the line

```
framework:
    validation:
        cache: validator.mapping.cache.apc
```

The cache needed to be changed to

```
        cache: validator.mapping.cache.doctrine.apc
```